# how to display arabic language in PDF

Tags: flutter, dart

I generate a PDF and data is retrieved from `TextField` if the texts are in English. The file will be created. If the texts are in Arabic, it is not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package like [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) and it will accept Arabic text